# Php Javascript Remove file from database that is being displayed in a while loop

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a database, in that database is a table with 2 columns:

```
Column 1: id
Column 2: filename
```

At the moment I have 3 entries in the table, each one has their own unique id (id is set to auto-increment with each entry). each separate entry has an id of:

```
1
2
3
```

I'm using a While loop in my page to display each item:

```
<?php 
 require_once("parse_files/connect.php");

 $query1 = "SELECT * FROM uploads";
 $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);
 while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
$upload_id = $row1['id'];
$upload_filename = $row1['filename'];
 ?>

     <?php echo $upload_filename?><br>
     <button onClick="remove_file();">Remove</button>

 <?php } ?>
```

Here I have echo'd out the filename, And next to it I have displayed a button that will allow the user to delete the file. For testing purposes I have created this small script to see what value my javascript pulls out when I click the button:

```
<script>
 function remove_file(){
var filename = '<?php echo $upload_id?>'
alert(filename);
 }
</script>
```

When I test it I place the script within the while loop, so that I can get the value of the id (Or so i hoped), but it just doesn't work. When I click the button next to the corresponding filename, I want it to show that products id, but instead it shows me the last entries (3) no matter which button I click. I might be taking the complete wrong direction with this, could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<button onClick="remove_file(<?php echo $upload_id;?>);">Remove</button>
```

Then in javascript:

```
function remove_file(id){
  alert(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do that in this way if you only want to alert that id

```
<button onClick="alert('<?php echo $upload_id;?>');">Remove</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm using this script for testing just to see if the value of id will work properly, I'm then going to put it through an ajax .post, so that will not be necessary, but thanks!